# Why does malloc() cause minor page fault?

Tags: c, malloc, virtual-memory, ps, page-fault

I'm trying to learn about memory and page fault, so I wrote the code below to check my understanding. I don't understand why calling malloc caused MINFL to increase since malloc() shouldn't affect physical memory (from what I understand).

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
  printf("Before malloc\n");
  getchar();
  
  malloc(1 << 20);
  printf("After malloc\n");
  getchar();
}
```

These are the terminal results of ps command.

Before malloc:
[image: Before malloc]

After malloc:
[image: After malloc]

There are 2 things I don't understand:

1. why does MINFL increase?
2. why does VSZ increase by 1028 and not 1024?

Please help and Thank you.

Comment: *why does MINFL increase*. It's difficult to say for sure without looking at the implementation details. But in general `malloc` will read/write to memory to maintain its data structures (e.g. used and free lists).

Comment: So ```malloc``` actually write to memory. This is new to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to **both of them** is the same and very simple indeed.

As you might know, Glibc `malloc` will use `mmap` to directly allocate a block larger than 128 KiB. However, it will need to write bookkeeping information *below* the pointer - because how else would `free` know what it should be done when just given a pointer. If you print the pointer that `malloc` returned, you'll see that it is *not* page aligned.

Here's a program that demonstrates all this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#define ALLOCATION_SIZE (1 << 20)

int main(void) {
    struct rusage usage = {0};

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
    printf("1st before malloc: %lu\n", usage.ru_minflt);

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
    printf("2nd before malloc: %lu\n", usage.ru_minflt);

    char *p = malloc(ALLOCATION_SIZE);
    printf("pointer returned from malloc: %p\n", p);

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
    printf("after malloc: %lu\n", usage.ru_minflt);

    p[0] = 42;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
    printf("after writing to the beginning of the allocation: %lu\n", usage.ru_minflt);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ALLOCATION_SIZE; i++) {
        p[i] = 42;
    }
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
    printf("after writing to every byte of the allocation: %lu\n", usage.ru_minflt);
}
```

outputs something like

```
1st before malloc: 108
2nd before malloc: 118
pointer returned from malloc: 0x7fbcb32aa010
after malloc: 119
after writing to the beginning of the allocation: 119
after writing to every byte of the allocation: 375
```

i.e. `getrusage` and `printf` cause page faults the first time around, so we call it twice - now the fault count is 118 before the `malloc` call, and after `malloc` it is 119. If you look at the pointer, 0x010 is not 0x000 i.e. the allocation is not page-aligned - those first 16 bytes contain bookkeeping information for `free` so that it knows that it needs to use `munmap` to release the memory block, and the size of the allocated block!

Now naturally this explains why the size increase was 1028 Ki instead of 1024 Ki - **one extra page** had to be reserved so that there would be enough space for those 16 bytes! It also explains the source of the page fault - because `malloc` had to write the bookkeeping information to the copy-on-write zeroed page. This can be proved by writing to the first byte of the allocation - it doesn't cause a page fault any longer.

Finally the for loop will modify the pages and touch the remaining 256 pages out of those **257** mapped in.

---

And if you change `ALLOCATION_SIZE` to `((1 << 20) - 16)` i.e. allocate just 16 bytes less, you'd see that the both virtual size and the number of page faults would match the values **you** were expecting.